# Definition of this argmax sigma function

Tags: graph-theory

I came across this function while studying about graphs. I don't really understand what it means:
$$
l(i)=\underset{l}{\operatorname{argmax}}\sum_{j\in N(i)}l(j)
$$
where

- $i$ and $j$ are nodes in the graph,
- $l(i)$ is labels of that node,
- $N(i)$ is the set of neighbours of node $i$

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56pLx.png)

I am a computer science student so a brief definition of what this function does in layman terms would be highly appreciated!

Source for the given formula : https://www.mdpi.com/631264

Comment: Thanks for the link. There is most likely a typo in the formula you cite. The formula should be $$l(i)=\underset{l}{\operatorname{argmax}}\sum_{j\in N(i)}l(j)$$ Сompare it to the image. I hope that everything is clear to you now.

Comment: Yes I updated the correct formula

Answer (score 0):

Every node $k$ has a label $l(k)$.  I think the intended meaning of the equation is to update the label of node $i$ to the label that appears most frequently among the neighbors of node $i$, but $\sum$ is not the proper symbol for that.  Also, the $l_{(j)}$ appears to be a typo for $l(j)$.

Comment: Hii
Yess it is a label propagation algorithm, and the label is updated according to that equation. I'm trying to recreate the codes for that, but I don't understand the use of summation in this

Comment: I think the authors are abusing $\sum$ to mean cardinality.